Update of Proton VPN on Ubuntu 20.04 locks out wifi & wired access!
I run Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on an HP Elitebook 8460p laptop.
I use Proton VPN that I load after I power on the laptop.
I have "NetShield" on to block ads, trackers and malware.
I have the "Kill Switch" enabled with the "advanced" setting "on".
I have Ubuntu Pro enabled so that I get more access to available updates.
Recently, through "Software & Updates" I downloaded an update for ProtonVPN.
Once that was complete, I restarted the Laptop.
When it was done booting I tried starting Proton VPN.
It failed to start. I had NO WIFI access.
I had a very long list of errors in my system Logs.
I went to the Synaptic Pkg app and uninstalled Proton VPN and all its Dependencies.
Then I powered off and restarted the laptop.
That didn't allow me to reinstall Proton VPN and the "Kill Switch" was still enabled,
even though I had uninstalled Proton VPN and all its Dependencies!
I Still had NO WIFI access! I even used a WIRED connection and it remained locked.
I had NO internet access whatsoever.
I got frustrated after an hour of trying everything to run Proton VPN,
and I reloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 live disk and basically erased the drive and did a "Restore" of a backup (Deja Dup) I had made 5 days previously.
All that solved my problem and I was able to run Proton VPN as if nothing went wrong.
So..I've come to the conclusion that the "Kill Switch" being enabled when I ran the Update for Proton VPN, caused all my problems...??
Am I wrong or should I have turned off the "Kill Switch" BEFORE I ran the Update for Proton VPN?
That's my first question.
BTW..I'm planning on upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.
Should I just skip right to upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04?
That's my 2nd question.
Thank you for your help and answers to my questions.
Rick White

Contact Pronto and ask them for any question related to their product. This site is one question per post but since your second question will be deleted by the mods I will give you some info. You are asking for an opinion not allowed on this site.

Thanks. Sorry for the violation. Delete my question(s) if you wish.
I'll contact Proton re: the issue and I'll contact Ubuntu Forums for my version question.
Bye.

Actually it's not that difficult to solve, check the active routes, usually you can see proton connections with
ip route show

it will list your current routes, if you see proton's link up and running such as "default via xxx.xxx.x.x dev pvp......" then you have to bring it down:
sudo ip link set dev nameofinterface down

this will terminate proton's route.
you can check Proton's log or just launch the app via terminal protonvpn-app if it prints the errors then check what packages you're missing. You can also check missing dependencies with pip check
After installing the missing packages you can re-install Proton VPN

do notice bringing down the route once it's not a permanent solution, you have to completely remove ProtonVPN, deleting routes also or fix missing packages.

OP was not asking how to remove the VPN software.

@DavidDE the point in my answer is not about removing the ProtonVPN but how to bring up the internet connection since it was blocked by ProtonVPN interface, there can be even a bug with ProtonVPN. So you have to bring down that route which most likely was set by KillSwitch setting (OP also mentioned that). After that you can completely remove it still (and reboot preferably) and install the VPN again.

Alternatively, if you managed to restore the access to the internet without removing the ProtonVPN but it still doesn't want to connect, assuming if you use Wireguard, you can try to reset wireguard modprobe -r wireguard && sudo modprobe wireguard it should do the trick too.
